# Bootstrap modal window file upload and send to email

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have modal window with file upload. There's a button "send to email". How to create function that sends uploaded file to email?

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch Modal
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-fullscreen-lg-down">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="file-loading">
          <input id="input-b9" name="input-b9[]" multiple type="file">
        </div>
        <div id="kartik-file-errors"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send to email</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#input-b9").fileinput({
        showPreview: false,
        showUpload: false,
        elErrorContainer: '#kartik-file-errors',
        allowedFileExtensions: ["pdf", "doc", "docx"]
        //uploadUrl: '/site/file-upload-single'
    });
});
</script>
```

https://codepen.io/PineappleBros/pen/KKoENrN

Comment: You can't send emails with client side Javascript. Well, technically you can, but it would require exposing your email password in your source code, which is obviously not done. You'll need a server side script to handle sending emails for you like NodeJS or PHP.

Answer (score 1):

As @icecub pointed out, you cannot send emails directly from client side JS. Instead:

- Include a `<form>`-element into your modal (preferrably with `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and `action="path/to/backend/script"`
- On `click`ing the "send to email" button (or `submit`ting the form), collect the values of the `<form>` into a `FormData` object. The easiest way to do this is to pass the complete `<form>` element into the `FormData` constructur:

```
formEl.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault(); // <-- keep the browser from reloading on form submission
  fetch(e.target.action, // <-- points to backend script
        {
          // ... elided ...
          body: new FormData(e.target) // <-- create FormData object from <form>
          // ... elided ...
        }
  ).then(
     // ... elided ...
  );
});
```

- Send the `FormData` object via `XMLHttpRequest/Fetch/whatever-you-use` to a backend script (might be PHP, Python, NodeJS, Ruby, ...)
- Let the backend script read the `FormData`, then let it assemble and send an email
- Send a success or failure message back to the client (via JSON/XML/whatever-you-use)